64 bit operating windows computer downloading ffmpeg
Im having trouble downloading ffmpeg to my computer, I need to download version 4.2.2. I need to download this to use ImpactControlCenter in order to video record using my balluf blueFOX3 camera. This is the file I downloaded https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/latest/ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl-shared.zip
I keep on getting errors however when I try to video record.


And what trouble is it that you have? You downloaded ffmpeg and and the software doesn’t pick it up? Or you can’t find a download?

The title is about "downloading", but the body seems to describe issues installing.

@DanielB I am not even sure i installed it and even put it in the environment variable and still wont work

Please provide a link to what you downloaded. It could’ve been the .exe when you need the .dlls.

@DanielB I downloaded this https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/latest/ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl-shared.zip

@DanielB I update the question

@DrMoishePippik yes its installing

@DanielB would I need to download the shared version? Also, do I need to download the gpl or the lgpl?

The version you indicate you downloaded isn’t ffmpeg 4.2.2, as demanded by the program you’re trying to use. Instead, you downloaded the very bleeding edge of ffmpeg development, which is even newer than ffmpeg 7.
On the download page you found, the latest release that has ffmpeg any 4.x version is this one: Auto-Build 2024-03-31 17:28
This is ffmpeg 4.4, not 4.2.2. This may or may not work. If it doesn’t, it’s not looking good. I was not able to find Windows builds for ffmpeg 4.2.2 on the net. You would have to build it yourself.

If you want to go with the environment variable and a custom location, you will probably have to point the variable at the “bin” folder of the extracted ZIP archive.

would I need to download the shared version? Also, do I need to download the gpl or the lgpl?

Yes, the “shared” variant is the one you need (with the .dlls). The dialog says LGPL, so either might work.

Zips of ffmpeg-4.2.2-win64-static, plus ffmpeg-4.2.2-win32-static, ffmpeg-4.2.2-MacOs64-static, and ffmpeg-4.2.2.tar.bz2 for Linux are here at https://www.videohelp.com/software/ffmpeg/old-versions

Those will not work. OP needs the shared build, with .dlls.
